# ffmpeg combine multitrack audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have three audio files which I am attempting to combine into a multitrack audio file.

```sh
ffmpeg -i A.wav -i B.mp3 -i C.wav -map 0 out.mp4
```

But the result seems to be (testing with `ffmpeg -i`) just a single track.

It is possible to get all tracks?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ffmpeg -i A.wav -i B.mp3 -i C.wav -c copy -map 0:a -map 1:a -map 2:a out.mp4
```